# Google Dataflow jobs stuck analysing the graph

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have submitted a couple of jobs that seem to have stuck on the graph analyzing step.

A weird error appears on top of the Google Dataflow jobs list page:

> A job with ID "2018-01-19_03_27_48-15138951989738918594" doesn't exist

Also, trying to list it using `gcloud` tool shows them as in `Unknown` state:

```
JOB_ID                                    NAME              TYPE       CREATION_TIME        STATE      REGION
2018-01-19_03_27_48-15138951989738918594  myjobname2  Streaming  2018-01-19 12:27:48  Unknown    europe-west1
2018-01-19_03_21_05-1065108814086334743   myjobname   Streaming  2018-01-19 12:21:06  Unknown    europe-west1
```

Trying to cancel them using `gcloud` tool as well doesn't work either:
`$ gcloud beta dataflow jobs --project=myproject cancel 2018-01-19_03_21_05-1065108814086334743`

> Failed to cancel job [2018-01-19_03_21_05-1065108814086334743]: (9027838c1500ddff): Could not cancel workflow; user does not have sufficient permissions on project: myproject, or the job does not exist in the project.

Any idea?

Comment: Same thing happened to me when trying to stopping two different batch jobs. I was able to stop the jobs in the console by clicking 'stop job' under Job status but got the same permissions error through both local shell and cloud shell. Feels like a temporary issue with the DataFlow service, it worked doing pretty much the same thing yesterday.

Comment: I cannot even stop the job as, when I click on the job itself, `The graph is still being analysed` message appears along with a blank screen.

Comment: Finally the jobs were errored because I ran another job that took all the available quota for that region and the stuck jobs failed as they could not acquire the required resources.